# How to delete Auth Token From Application Class For sign Out Functionality in Twitter app in android

Tags: android, twitter

I Want to remove Auth token from Application Class,In My Twitter app How can I do this Please help me

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

there is no need to remove auth token, u just need to post one query to twitter api as follow. it will delete all store cookies and tokens stored by twitter.

```
public void logoutToTwitter() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.twitter.com/1/account/end_session.format");
    try {

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
       httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   } }
```

just call the above method on your "twitter logout button"

enjoy the code.

Comment: where i have to write this code..in Application Class or Time Line Activity

Comment: here we are not familiar to your project code ..so, you can call this function where you want remove tokens

Comment: @Tarishi that to know how to logout from the twitter actually..cause i have seen everywhere everyone just deletes the stored token that they have stored in sharedpreference or static variable and says user that "You are successffully logged out"...so this is the better thing to do. I THINK SO.

Comment: I got An error in Log Cat That is.. twitter4j.TwitterException: Read error: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Answer (score 0):

```
TwitterApp mTwitter = new TwitterApp(MyProfile.this, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
                                    Constants.TWITTER_SECRET_KEY);
mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
```

This much worked well for me, ussing the twitter4j. Just calling the resetAccessToken is equivalent to logout.